# Django admin, foreign key field in list_editable

Tags: django, django-admin

Hi fellow django users,

How can I add a field from a related object in the `list_editable` admin property?

```
# models.py
class Order(Model):
    reference = CharField(max_length=25)

class Product(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    order = ForeignKey(Order)

# admin.py
class ProductAdmin:
    list_display = ('name', 'order_reference')
    list_editable = ('name', 'order__reference') # <--- THIS !

    def order_reference(self, obj):
        return obj.order.reference
```

I tried it this way, but it won't work. I also tried to add a property in the `Product` class, but nope, it won't work either. Any clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable):

> list_editable interacts with a couple of other options in particular
>   ways; you should note the following rules:
>
> 1. **Any field in list_editable must also be in list_display.** You can't edit a field that's not displayed!
> 2. The same field can't be listed in both list_editable and list_display_links -- a field can't be both a form and a link.
> 3. You'll get a validation error if either of these rules are broken.

Notice that you use *order_reference* and *order__reference* in **list_display** and **list_editable**, respectively. So in short, I don't think you can do this easily. If you want to have inspiration, you could check out the implementation of [pageadmin.py in django-cms](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/admin/pageadmin.py), but it's NOT straightforward!!

Comment: Furthermore, let me add that what you want to do does not entirely make sense: What if the same object is related twice? Then you'll have two form fields representing the SAME related instance. Which is not going to work at all!

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I know it's not straightforward, otherwise I wouldn't ask :) I don't understand your comment. I could want to update different fields from a same related objects, for example to update some profile fields in a user admin module.

Comment: Here's an example of what I meant in the comment: Say you have two Product instances and they both refer to the same Order. Then you would have two form fields (for order__reference) in the list pointing to the same order.

Comment: Ok, makes things clearer. You are right, this does'nt really make sense.