# how to add to django admin list_editable a reverse relation Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

These are my simple models.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
     phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name


class Box(models.Model):
     customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='box')
     box_status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

these are my model admin classes.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Customer, Box


@admin.register(Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'box_status']
     list_editable = ['phone', 'box_status']

     def box_status(self, obj):
        det = list(obj.box.values_list('box_status', flat=True))
        return det

   @admin.register(Box)
   class BoxAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        pass
```

Now box_status from related model can work list_display but not working in list_editable.
the error is

```
<class 'django.forms.widgets.admin_class'>: (admin.E121) The value of 'list_editable[1]' refers to 'box_status', which is not an attribute of 'newapp.Customer'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django admin, foreign key field in list\_editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398797/django-admin-foreign-key-field-in-list-editable)

Comment: @PyMaster No it doesn't work it is for direct relation on foreign key the question i am asking is about reverse relation.